# How to sum list of pandas boolean series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have more than 2 boolean series in pandas.

when I do & or +

```
search[0] & search[1]
```

I correctly get a boolean series

```
search[0] & search[1]
0     True
1    False
```

but I need something like sum(search) which gets an array of series returns a boolean series as well.

```
sum(search)
0    2
1    0
```

here's example code that works, I was hoping there was a way to do this natively:

```
def sum_bool_series(bool_list):
      r = bool_list[0]
      for l in bool_list[1:]:
          r = r & l
      return r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert one of the Series to integers, the other(s) will be casted to integer automatically:

```
s1 = pd.Series([True, False, False, True])
s2 = pd.Series([True, False, True, False])

s1.astype(int)+s2
```

output:

```
0    2
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```

In contrast:

```
s1+s2 # or s1&s2

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question, I simply want a nice way to do sum(LIST OF BOOLEAN SERIES) that will return a BOOLEAN SERIES.

Comment: Then the question is unclear to me, can you please provide a fully reproducible dataframe constructor and the matching expected output?